# How to compute exact complexity of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

Without resorting to asymptotic notation, is tedious step counting the only way to get the time complexity of an algorithm? And without step count of each line of code can we arrive at a big-O representation of any program?

Details: trying to find out the complexity of several numerical analysis algorithms to decide which will be best suited for solving a particular problem. 
  E.g. - from among Regula-Falsi or Newton-Rhapson method for solving eqns, intention is to evaluate the exact complexity of each method and then decide (putting value of 'n' or whatever arguments there are) which method is less complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way --- not the "easy" or hard way but the only reasonable way --- to find the exact complexity of a complicated algorithm is to profile it.  A modern implementation of an algorithm has a complex interaction with numerical libraries and with the CPU and its floating point unit.  For instance in-cache memory access is much faster than out-of-cache memory access, and on top of that there may be more than one level of cache.  Counting steps is really much more suitable to the asymptotic complexity that you say isn't enough for your purpose.

But, if you did want to count steps automatically, there are also ways to do that.  You can add a counter increment command (like "bloof++;" in C) to every line of code, and then display the value at the end.

You should also know about the more refined time complexity expression, f(n)*(1+o(1)), that is also useful for analytical calculations.  For instance n^2+2*n+7 simplifies to n^2*(1+o(1)).  If the constant factor is what bothers you about usual asymptotic notation O(f(n)), this refinement is a way to keep track of it and still throw out negligible terms.

Comment: the simplification will be helpful thanks.
 could you tell me more/point me to the necessary resources on how to 'profile' the complicated algorithms.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29 . I am not an expert in fancy development tools, but that Wikipedia page can get you started.  In particular, it mentions the classic Unix profiling command "gprof".

Answer (score 2):

The 'easy way' is to simulate it. Try your algorithms with lots of values of n and lots of different data, plot the results then match the curve on the graph to an equation.

Your results may not be strictly correct and they're only as valid as your ability to generate good test data but for most cases this will work.

Answer (score 0):

> E.g. - from among Regula-Falsi or Newton-Rhapson method for solving eqns, intention is to evaluate the exact complexity of each method and then decide (putting value of 'n' or whatever arguments there are) which method is less complex.

I don't think it's possible to answer this question in general for nonlinear solvers.  You could an exact number of computations per iteration, but you're never going to know in general how many iterations it will take for each solver to converge.  There are other complications like needing the Jacobian for Newton's which could make computing the complexity even more difficult.

To sum up, the most efficient nonlinear solver is always dependent on the problem you're solving.  If the variety of problems you're solving is very limited, doing a bunch of experiments with different solvers and measuring the number of iterations and CPU time will probably give you more useful information.